# How to clone Git repo on my local server

Tags: windows, linux, git

I'm trying to use Git for the first time (I have used Mercurial before so I know the basic setup).

Everything is ready on the server side with the following properties:

- User name: git
- Domain: mydomain.com
- Port: 222
- Repo path: /home/git/repo.git
- Public key saved in: /home/git/.ssh/authorized_key
- Private key saved on my local Windows machine.
- The key pair was generated with PuTTYgen

During installation of Git on my Windows machine I chose OpenSSH if that matters.

So my question is, how do I check out my repo?

Thanks.

Comment: PuTTYgen generates the key in different format than OpenSSH expects. Do you have it in openssh format in `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\id_rsa` and `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\id_rsa.pub` as OpenSSH expects?

Comment: Note that Git Gui has a menu for generating/showing the ssh key. That's the easiest way to generate it so that it is properly set up for git.

Answer (score 1):

`git clone username@server:/path/to/git/repo.git` while you are in the folder where you want to check out to.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I specify my custom port (222) and where my private key is?

Comment: These are probably the answers you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7772190/passing-ssh-options-to-git-clone

Answer (score 0):

Use `[user@]host:relpath` to clone over SSH, or `ssh://[user@]host[:port]/abspath` if you need to specify a different port.

For your current configuration:

```
ssh://git@mydomain.com:222/home/git/repo.git
```

or

```
ssh://git@mydomain.com:222/~/repo.git
```

---

With OpenSSH, you need to export your private key to OpenSSH format (using PuTTYgen), then either a) save it as `~/.ssh/id_rsa` or `~/.ssh/id_dsa` depending on the type, or b) save it anywhere you like, then edit [`~/.ssh/config`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh_config) `IdentityFile` to point to the file. (*a* is better if you use the same key to connect everywhere; *b* is better if you use different keys for different servers.)

On Windows, the location is `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh`, and you'll probably need to create the `.ssh` directory yourself using Command Prompt.

If you had chosen PuTTY/plink, you could double-click the `.ppk` key file to load it to Pageant, and it would be used automatically.